# No controls when watching my own replays

Tags: dota-2

I am recording Dota 2 using the following method (using console commands)

1. join game
2. open console
3. type "record myawesomereplay"
4. play
5. open console again
6. type "stop"

It can saved and there is no problem. But, when I run the demo, It does not show the controls on the top right (eg. view modes - free mode, directed camera, the move forward, play pause controls etc.). I am also not able to edge pan.
Any solutions to this ?

Answer (score 3):

Click the eyeball in the top right. This will bring up the spectator controls and allow you to change perspective and etc. as you'd like to. Here's an example (although old):

[image: Replay UI]